# Can not update Stock Availability / Is In Stock value via Magento API

Tags: c#, .net, api, magento

### Background

I have a live and test Magento store. I generate a MagentoApi C# class from the WSDL of the Magento store.

### Problem

I am able to update product quantities with no issues via my API class. I am now trying to set the `Stock Availability` field from the API but it will not change it's value.

### Code

```
[Test]
public void UpdateIsInStockField()
{
    MagentoStoreConfig storeConfig = GetTestMagentoStore();
    var magentoApiRepo = new MagentoApiRepository(storeConfig);
    catalogInventoryStockItemEntity magentoProduct = magentoApiRepo.GetProductFromSku(new[] { "SKU-123456" });

    var productUpdated = new catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity
                      {
                          is_in_stock = 0,
                          manage_stock = 0,
                          use_config_manage_stock = 0,
                          qty = new Random().Next(50, 100).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                      };

    magentoApiRepo.UpdateStockQuantity(magentoProduct.product_id, productUpdated);
}
```

### Result

From the Magento store's admin section, the quantity value changes for the product but the `Stock Availability` value has not changed.

I am setting the `manage_stock` and `use_config_manage_stock` as per the instructions outlined [here in the Magento API reference guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/cataloginventory_stock_item#examples).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that I need to specify that I am supplying the `is_in_stock` field by adding the parameter `is_in_stock_specified=true`.

So, my API call is as follows:

```
var productUpdated = new catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity
                      {
                          is_in_stock_specified = true,
                          is_in_stock = 0,
                          manage_stock = 0,
                          use_config_manage_stock = 0,
                          qty = new Random().Next(50, 100).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                      };
```

Comment: Just saved me between 1 hour and 45 days on this stupid bug .

Comment: Glad it helped, it seems to be a common pattern in the Magento API. If you ever see a property with a `_specified` boolean you should probably set it to true if you are using it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me using SOAPv1. I guess I have to put in 45 days and try to regrow my hair.

Comment: @hogan it definitely worked for me and the OP. Can you post a question and we can take a look...

Comment: @Seany84 thank you for your offer to help. I tested different scenarios and got it to work using `$stockItemData = [ 'manage_stock'=>'1', 'use_config_manage_stock'=>'0', 'is_in_stock' => 1, 'qty' => '25',];` note that this is php syntax. For some weird reason it seems that here the order of the entries was relevant and I also had a typo in the call. It works now. Thank you.

Comment: Just saved my bacon! Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much is_in_stock_specified=true worked for me